# How to identify whether Google SMTP server has been blocked when used by an application to send emails

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

My web application sends email to users on certain business events. For this im using a Google SMTP server with both username password mode as well as OAuth 2.0.

Other props are as follows :

```
 smtpHost: smtp.gmail.com
 smtpPort: 587
```

Now the issue is, after some emails being marked as spams Google blocks the domain and the account. Is there a way to avoid happening this? And is there a way to identify the error thrown when tries to send the email when the domain is blocked, so I can create an alert about the domain and account being blocked.. For now its not possible to access the past logs either, but can get access to the new logs. Suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah. Buy a domain for $5.00. Go to rackspace.com and by an email account for $2.99 to use with this domain. Congratulations. You now have an email account that you pay for with much higher limits. You are being blocked because you are not using Gmail for its intended use.

Comment: what do you mean by not using Gmail for its intended use?

Comment: It is not mean to be used by programmers for business with clients. Gmail will blacklist anyone who appears to be doing stuff “out of the ordinary”. Using OAUTH will mitigate some of that, but getting mail scopes now requires a lot of assurances that you’re not doing something weird and potentially external validation of your platform for security and privacy.